# How to count in 4 dimensions an infinite set of 3rd degree polynomials (with integer coefficients a,b,c,d) using Cantors diagonilaziation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been solving the problem whether or not the set of 3rd degree polynomials is countable and after much effort concluded that it is:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/comments/4cf9ba/is_the_set_of_all_3rd_degree_polynomials/

Now what I cant come up with is a way to enumrate them in a diagonal like this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

My 3rd degree polynomials got 4 coefficients. I tried enumrating like this:
Bijection: N -> a,b,c,d as integers

0 = 1000

1 = 1100

2 = 1110

3 = 1111

4 = 2111

But this is not a diagonal.
Because I would need to deal with missing terms
1010
1001
1101

If I try it differently just incrementing one term I get into situations like this:
99 0 0 0

999 0 0 0

99999 0 0 0

And I cant get to 99999 0 0 1 for example

How do I diagonilize in 4 dimensions or even 3? Couldn't find any example whatsoever.

Thanks :)

Comment: In neither this post nor the reddit thread you linked to does it mention which set the coefficients of these polynomials are coming from. Do you mean rational coefficients? If so, there are only countably many.

Comment: @mad_algebraist: In the Reddit thread it is explicitly asked about *integer coefficients*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagonal argument is used for proving one set is larger than another (reals vs. naturals, for example), so is the wrong tool for this problem.  Assuming you are taking coefficients to be integers as the title says, you are looking to prove that the set of four-tuples of integers is countable.  It is easiest to start by proving that the set of pairs of naturals is countable.  There are many ways-you can use [Cantor's pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), you can use $(a,b) \to 2^a3^b$, and others.  Now just view the four-tuple as an ordered pair of ordered pairs and you can inject the four-tuples into the naturals.  Finally make the correspondence between the integers and naturals for each of the four elements of your four-tuple and you are done.  It is very common to make a chain of injections to prove a set is countable.

Comment: Thanks! I got confused. But maybe this post will help somebody else latter.